# Angular Custom Components

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 4 in my application.

How to run a component always in background , and that should not be visible untill we pass some values to that component/directive.  when we pass some values to component/directive which is running in background it should be open on top current component(current view page) some thing like alert message.  **it should not disturb current flow of execution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are many points in your question :)

1. ***Should not be visible untill we pass some values to that component/directive***

You can use `*ngIf` for this. You can set the flag based on some conditional value governed by its parent component.

```
<my-component *ngIf="display"></my-component>
```

Using CSS, you can keep its width/height to cover the whole HTML.

2. ***It should be open on top current component(current view page) some thing like alert message***

Set CSS: `z-index: 999` (any value more than 1)

3. ***It should not disturb current flow of execution***

As per my understanding, if you want to just make it display at the top of your view, but also want to keep displaying the main view behind it, you can make its `opacity: .5` (CSS) and achieve this.